# TFS2010 - How do I checkin the result from one solution into another?

Tags: tfs, msbuild

So I've got one solution that compiles to a C++ DLL
I've got another solution that is a WPF app.

Both of these solutions live in the same TeamProject on our TFS server.

I want to automate the build process so that when the C++ solution builds on the server, if it's successful it automatically checks the result into the WPF solution.

Thanks in advance for the hep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I haven't worked my whole way through the solution to this the correct place to start is with something like -
http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2010/11/03/performing-checkins-in-tfs-2010-build.aspx

For a more comprehensive walktrhough on creating custom build templates:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/02/12/how-to-create-a-custom-workflow-activity-for-tfs-build-2010.aspx

Now I just need to figure out how to map the workspaces, setup the file outputs so that I can check the dlls back in, but the templates are now working.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to setup [TFS Dependency Replicator](http://tfsdepreplicator.codeplex.com).

This example config will wait for MyBuildType to finish, then checkin /Release/MyAssembly.dll from the build output directory to $/Trunk/Dependencies/MyAssembly.dll:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Rules>
 <Rule
   BuildType="MyBuildType"
   EventType="New"
   Source="/Release/MyAssembly.dll"
   Destination="$/Trunk/Dependencies/MyAssembly.dll" />
</Rules>
```

Comment: Hi Grant, excuse my ignorance on the subject, but can that rule be implemented on TFS-2010, or is it only for the 2005/2008 style build?

Comment: @Joel The rule is for TFS Dependency Replicator, not TFS itself. Since the replicator tool works with TFS 2005, 2008 and 2010 - it doesn't matter whether you're using the 2005/2008 MSBuild style or the 2010 Windows Workflow style.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly possible!

I don't know how many files you will have to change in the WPF solution, but the easiest way is to checkout and then checkin the relevant files using the appropriate [TFS command line commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0.aspx). There's an example in this post: [Visual Studio Build Tasks - TFS Operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770223/visual-studio-build-tasks-tfs-operations)

A second option is to create your own custom build task which will do the checkout/checkin for you.

Comment: But from the post you linked they talked about putting the command in the msbuild file, which I believe is what TFS-2008 used. Now in 2010 we've got these xaml process templates, that seem far more complicated.